# How to set settings in Elastic Search NEST 7.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

While indexing an item, it returns this error: 
index [] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];

I found a solution :
**curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'** 
source of solution : https://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2017/12/23/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api-read-only-elasticsearch-indices/

How to apply this settings with my ElasticClient object in NEST 7.x?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NEST 7.x

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var response = client.Indices.UpdateSettings(Indices.All, u => u
    .IndexSettings(i => i
        .Setting("index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete", false)
    )
);
```

Most settings have a method for them, but this one doesn't currently (will add it). Where a method doesn't exist, `.Setting()` can be used with the setting name and value. Passing `false` results in the same behaviour as passing `null`.

Comment: For completeness, looks like they've since implemented the method Russ mentioned as `UnlockBlocksReadOnlyAllowDelete`, accessible via `.IndexSettings(i => i.BlocksReadOnlyAllowDelete(false))`

Comment: Bit late to the party but do you know how to set a dynamic index setting to null (index shard allocation routing)? I saw you mentioned that passing false has the same behaviour as setting it to null however it doesn't seem to have the desired effect and still sets the setting to "false".